# Where should I check that the values are right, in the constructor or before passing the values as arguments?

Tags: php

Let's say that i'm writing a class that will make basic CRUD operations, so I want that all the values that are going to be inserted to the database are all in lowercase.
so, I make sure that the values are all in lower case in the constructor, like this for example:

```
class Insert {
  private $name;
  private $lastname;

  public function __construct($name, $lastname) {
    $this->name = strtolower($name);
    $this->name = strtolower($lastname);
  }
}
$obj = new Insert('Jhon', 'Doe');
```

Or before creating the instance, like this:

```
class Insert {
  private $name;
  private $lastname;

  public function __construct($name, $lastname) {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->name = $lastname;
  }
}
$obj = new Insert(strtolower('Jhon'), strtolower('Doe'));
```

Comment: This depends on your design. If it should be impossible to insert mixed case into the DB, you put it in the class. If it's context-dependent, you put it in the caller.

Answer (score 1):

I would set a [DTO](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) to format the values. Is more readable and your class doesn`t need to know if is strlower or not, only set the variables.

Class DTO:

```
class UserDto
{
    public $lastname;

    public $name;

    function __construct($name, $lastname)
    {
       $this->lastname = strtolower($lastname);
       $this->name = strtolower($name);
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```
$userDto = new UserDto('Jhon', 'Doe');
$obj = new Insert($userDto);
$obj->save();
```

And

```
class Insert
{
    private $name;
    private $lastname;

    public function __construct($userDto)
    {
        $this->name = $userDto->name;
        $this->lastname = $userDto->lastname;
    }
}
```

Now if sometime you need that the name and the lastname doesn´t need to be strolower anymore, the only thing that you need to do is change the class DTO without affect Insert class.